# Security-Check iFrame not beeing loaded when trying to create new facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

i am trying to create a facebook app, however the security check won't let me. There's an iframe which just will not load.

I have tried it with chrome, edge, safari, disabling McAffee, tried it on my smartphone without wifi connection but nothing worked.

Do you have any tips what i could try or does someone know about this problem?
Here is a screenshot of the error in chrome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCvZ5.jpg

This is how it looks like in edge:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgApG.jpg
It says "Cant show this content in an iframe.

For safari: there is simply nothing where the iframe should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved by time. Just tried it again a few hours later and it was working well now.

Answer (score 0):

Using edge instead of chrome solved this for me.